# Spring: getting an instance of prototype bean with specific args

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

If I have a bean like so:

```
@Lazy
public class MyBean{
    public MyBean(String argument){}

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyBean myBean(String argument){
        return new MyBean(argument);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get an instance of that bean via Provider, like so:

```
@Component
public class MyOtherBean{
    @Autowired
    private javax.inject.Provider<MyBean> myBean;

    public void operation(){
        MyBean bean = myBean.get(); //I would like to pass argument in when getting the bean
    }
}
```

I was also reading into @Lookup annotation, since it has similar (or the same?) effect, but I am using spring 3.1.1 where this annotation is not implemented yet I believe...
If what I am trying to do here can't be done this way, how would you go about such functionality?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationContext` gives you this ability.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Factory.class);
       // calls the @Bean factory method for the myBean bean with the argument provided
       ctx.getBean("myBean", "first"); 
       ctx.getBean("myBean", "second");
    }
}

@Configuration
class Factory {
    @Bean()
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyBean myBean(String arg) {
        return new MyBean(arg);
    }
}

class MyBean {
    public MyBean(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: javax.inject.Provider

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk So that `Provider` and Spring's `ObjectFactory` don't give you that option. You have to go through the `BeanFactory` (`ApplicationContext`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Two questions though if that's ok: 1. will this work for arbitrary number of arguments? 2. Is that a good practice or not really?

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk The method expects a varargs of `Object`s. These arguments will be passed in order when invoking the `@Bean` factory method. You are kind of coupled here since you have to know the signature of the factory method. For that reason, I wouldn't really consider it good practice. But if you have no choice...